# How to get error from my app

Tags: android-activity, compiler-errors

Am using sketchware android IDE and if any error occurred they are showing in dailog box.
It's a inbuid error In sketchware 
My question how can i show this error in **Activity**:

```
try {
    //code that may crash
} catch(Exception _e) {
    //here do something when try detects error
    Log.e("try/catch error", _e.toString());
}
```

But its not working. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this.

Example onbutton click:

```
try {

//Your Logic

}

catch(Exception e) {

String ErrorMsg = e.toString();


//ErroMsg Is your error value strore in string formate


}
```